# How to do is >> std::skipws >> through multiple indices of an array?

Tags: c++, iterator, fstream, istream

Let's say you have `std::array<int, SIZE> a`, and you have saved each element of `a` into a file in one line separated by a space.  Then you want to read them with a `std:istream& is` via:

```
is >> std::skipws >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> ... >> a[SIZE-1];
```

How to write this generically for any value of `SIZE`.  Even though there are other easy ways of doing this, I'm curious how it is done with this particular method.

Comment: how about a loop?

Comment: Does that really work?  Then you would have to write `std::skipws` in each iteration?  Or just once before `a[0]` and then loop starting from i=1?

Comment: Why would you need it in every iteration? `std::skipws` sets a flag that remains set until or unless it is cleared by a subsequent `std::noskipws`. It is also enabled *by default*.

Comment: there is no difference between your line and this two lines `is >> std::skipws >> a[0];   is >> a[1] >> a[2] >> ... >> a[SIZE-1];`

Comment: ..or `is >> std::skipws; is >> a[0];  is >> a[1]; is >> a[2]; ...; is >> a[SIZE-1];`

Comment: the question is unclear because we dont know what you mean with "other easy ways of doing this" and its also not completely clear what you mean with "this particular method"

Comment: Default behavior of `operator>>` on streams to skip white spaces before reading. So why `std::skipws` was added explicitly?

Comment: @MarekR Makes sense, since a preceding user of the stream may have used `std::noskipws`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to write this generically for any value of SIZE.

There are control structures for repeating an operation a variable number of times: **loops**.

For example:

```
is >> std::skipws;
for(auto& el : a) {
    is >> el;
}
```